# Lifecycle of a Raiblocks transaction

Tags: transactions, nano

Can anyone explain step-by-step the lifecycle of a Raiblocks transaction...in layman's terms?

Having trouble deciphering the whitepaper (see link below).

https://raiblocks.net/media/RaiBlocks_Whitepaper__English.pdf

Comment: I don't think it is possible to decipher the whitepaper of Raiblocks. It sounds almost like an advertisement: *"near instantaneous transaction speed and unlimited scalability"*, *"the premier
cryptocurrency for consumer transactions"* ...

Comment: I am starting to get the same feeling.  Looking at Colin's -- the founder of Raiblocks -- posts on bitcoin talk, he does not talk in simple terms making it even more difficult to decipher.  This in contrast to Satoshi -- whose posts were so clear, simple and elegant.